# No signature of method: build_hash$_copyRecursively_closure3.doCall() is applicable for argument types

Tags: java, groovy

I'm really stuck with this error. It does not make any sense to me. Why argument types `UnixPath, null` ? I tried to print the `tempDir` variable and it's as expected - e.i. Path object with the correct path.

Any ideas?

> No signature of method: build_76p6jmah0vklon2l29au5dqlcr$_copyRecursively_closure3.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (sun.nio.fs.UnixPath, null) values: [generic/bundle, ...]
>     Possible solutions: doCall(), doCall(java.lang.Object), findAll(), findAll()

```
readFile(args[Property.CONFIG_FILE.propertyName]).eachLine {
        if (new File(it).isDirectory()) {
            copyRecursively(Paths.get(it), tempDir)
        } else {
            println "File $it is not a directory. Skipping."
        }
    }


void copyRecursively(Path sourceDir, Path destinationDir) {
    Files.walkFileTree(sourceDir, [FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS] as Set, Integer.MAX_VALUE, [
            postVisitDirectory: { return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE },
            preVisitDirectory: {filePath, attrs ->
                Path newDirectory = destinationDir.resolve(sourceDir.relativize(filePath));
                Files.copy(filePath, newDirectory, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            },
            visitFile: { filePath, attrs ->
                Files.copy(filePath, destinationDir.resolve(sourceDir.relativize(filePath)), StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            },
            visitFileFailed: { return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE }
    ] as java.nio.file.FileVisitor)
}
```

Comment: Is `copyRecursively` method defined in the same scope/script?

Comment: It is. I have other methods just like this one there too and they work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because of the `FileVisitor` object has not bean properly constructed. Methods `visitFileFailed` & `postVisitDirectory` expects two arguments, but you have provided none. After fixing the issue, correct method definition for `copyRecursively` would be:

```
void copyRecursively(Path sourceDir, Path destinationDir) {
    FileVisitor visitor =[
            preVisitDirectory : { Path filePath, BasicFileAttributes attrs ->
                Path newDirectory = destinationDir.resolve(sourceDir.relativize(filePath))
                Files.copy(filePath, newDirectory, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
            },
            visitFile         : { Path filePath, BasicFileAttributes attrs ->
                Files.copy(filePath, destinationDir.resolve(sourceDir.relativize(filePath)), StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
            },
            visitFileFailed   : { file, IOException ex -> return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE },
            postVisitDirectory: { dir, IOException ex -> return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE }
    ] as FileVisitor
    Files.walkFileTree(sourceDir, [FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS] as Set, Integer.MAX_VALUE, visitor)
}
```